# How to clean projects with Premake5?

Tags: premake

I know how to generate solutions and projects with premake5 with an action like vs2013.
However, how can I remove all generated files without relying on git clean? Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

As [this issue](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues/278) said, this action has still not been ported yet (Actually, if you run: premake5 clean, it will show the same description and won't do anything).
However I found that you can write your own ver. of action to clean the build by writing a `newaction`. 
Suppose you build your solution at `./build`, then you can write a `newaction` like:

```
-- Clean Function --
newaction {
   trigger     = "clean",
   description = "clean the software",
   execute     = function ()
      print("clean the build...")
      os.rmdir("./build")
      print("done.")
   end
}
```

Then run `premake5 clean` at the same folder of `premake5.lua`, and you will see  it will clean for you.

Comment: I like the idea of defining clean, but in this case os.rmdir() will only delete an empty directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835565/lua-delete-non-empty-directory for different ways to delete any directory. In the end I combined both ideas: I defined a newaction "clean" with a command that can delete even non-empty dirs (if the command is os-specific, make sure to define the newaction for each os).

Answer (score 0):

Po-Han's answer is a good way to do a centralized cleanup across all projects in the build. If you have some project-specific cleanup you would like to do as well, you can just wrap it in a conditional:

```
if _ACTION == "clean" then
   os.rmdir("./something")
end
```